# selenium java click middle of browser window to pause embedded video

Tags: java, selenium

I know this isn't good practice but I need it as a quick fix.

```
Dimension window = driver.manage().window().getSize();
new Actions(driver)
        .moveByOffset(window.getHeight() / 2, window.getWidth() / 2)
        .click()
        .build()
        .perform();
```

seemed to not click on the video. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are talking about flash testing in selenium. We need to download the flash jar for selenium before proceeding with.Below code might give you some idea.

```
public class Testyoutube {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

// Open firefox browser
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

// Maximize browser
driver.manage().window().maximize();

// FlashObjectWebDriver is seperate class which is available inside jar which we have    //attached
FlashObjectWebDriver flashApp = new FlashObjectWebDriver(driver, "movie_player");

// Pass the URL of video
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7igozQAdBMs");
Thread.sleep(2000);

// let the video load
while (Integer.parseInt(flashApp.callFlashObject("getPlayerState")) == 3)  {
Thread.sleep(1000);
}

// Play the video for 10 seconds
Thread.sleep(10000);

// pause video using pauseVideo method
flashApp.callFlashObject("pauseVideo");

Thread.sleep(5000);

// play video using playVideo method
flashApp.callFlashObject("playVideo");
Thread.sleep(5000);

// Seek to is method which will forword video to 140 second
flashApp.callFlashObject("seekTo","140","true");

// Wait for 5 seconds
Thread.sleep(5000);

//mute video using playVideo method
flashApp.callFlashObject("mute");

// Wait for 5 seconds
Thread.sleep(5000);

//set the volume of  video using setVolume method
flashApp.callFlashObject("setVolume","50");

// wait for 5 seconds
Thread.sleep(5000);

}
```

**Note:** I haven't tested this but it should work.
**Reference:**http://learn-automation.com/flash-testing-with-selenium-webdriver/

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the help. unfortunately It doesn't seem to be working-- the flashapp never grabs the video object. I suspect because the flash video isn't a youtube one.